# How a django form is passed to a html template

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I am new in Django framework and trying to understand how it works and what is its structure. I am just curious about how a django form is passed to a html template ? Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: As a form object, or is this not what you mean?

Comment: I think it's best to follow the Django tutorial as it covers forms and templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are curious in how django converts a python object into HTML, its internal mechanism, so the tutorial might not cover what it is.

I did have the same question before, but if you do look at code  in `forms.py` https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py you will see that internally there are methods which will look at the attributes of the objects that you have declared and generate snipplets of html code which will then be rendered.

Of course I cant tell you exactly how it works, I leave the heavy lifting to django.. Isn't that why we use a modern web framework like django in the first place.

Hope you will find this useful